# remove all characters up to £ and remove last character ]

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following option text that I want to put into a variable plus remove all characters except the value after the £ then convert it to a number. In this case 28.00

```
<option value="294">Set of 2 Boots</option><option value="295">Set of 4 Boots[Add £28.00]</option>
```

This converts the selects options text correctly.

```
recal_var = jQuery('select').find('option:selected').text();
```

But this doesn't seem to work with the £ symbol. If i change everything to a $ symbol I have no problems

```
price_result = parseFloat(recal_var.split('[Add £')[1].slice(0,-1).replace(/,/g,''));
```

I have also tried these as well with no luck.

```
price_result = parseFloat(recal_var.split('[Add &#163;')[1].slice(0,-1).replace(/,/g,''));

price_result = parseFloat(recal_var.split('[Add &pound;')[1].slice(0,-1).replace(/,/g,''));
```

What I get in firebug is recal_var.split("[Add \uFFFD")[1] is undefined

page has this metatag, not sure if that makes a difference.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: +1 for "here's several ways I tried to solve the problem" before asking for help.

Comment: I made a few updates to my question above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str = "Set of 4 Boots[Add £28.00]";
var costStr = str.match(/£([\d.]+)/);
if(costStr){
    var cost = parseFloat(costStr[1]);
    alert(cost);
}
```

Example: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ibayiz)

EDIT ignoring the £ and relying on position at end:

```
var str = "Set of 4 Boots[Add £28.00]";
var costStr = str.match(/([\d.]+)\]$/);
if(costStr){
    var cost = parseFloat(costStr[1]);
    alert(cost);
}
```

To match comma

```
var str = "Set of 4 Boots[Add £28,133.00]";
var costStr = str.match(/([\d.,]+)\]$/);
if(costStr){
    var cost = parseFloat(costStr[1].replace(/,/g,""));
    alert(cost);
}
```

Comment: While I would agree that it is working as it should in your example, for some reason it does not in mine. when I check the variable console.log(recal_var); it shows Set of 4 Boots[Add £28.00] but if I plug in var costStr = recal_var.match(/£([\d.]+)/); I do not get an alert

Comment: Make an example page with the problem.

Comment: You could also change the reg exp to `/([\d.]+)\]$/`

Comment: Ok, your second code is working. Can you explain the regex, please and will it work for different size numbers 2,800.00, 28,000.00, etc...

Comment: It says capture any digit `\d` or decimal/period that comes before a `]` and end of line `$`. It would fail with your comma examples because the since it is not in the regular expression. It would only match `800.00` and `000.00`. To match the comma, it would have to be included inside of the `[\d.,]`. BUT than the , would fail with parseFloat. :)

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks for all your help and explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possibly a charset mismatch? The meta tag says UTF-8, but what Content-Type is the page served with?

Comment: Not sure, how would I find that out?

Comment: Tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)

Comment: You can see the HTTP headers in firebug, too.